# Using two different DB (MySQL and Postgres) for a single Rails App

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a rails app that uses MySQL for authentication and storing models. I currently am thinking of using PostgreSQL for analytics (by taking advantage of its special data types like arrays and KV pairs). I am just wondering how I would be able to have two types of databases (1 for models and authentication and 1 for analytics) when trying to save records using ActiveRecord. I want to save the model for analytics in Postgres and other models in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to migrate completely to PostgresSQL if you want to use it for anything. It'll make your life a lot simpler.

I believe your best answer otherwise will be to stop inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base for your models here. Instead include ActiveRecord, and manually call establish_connection.

But yeah, just migrate to PG. It'll save a lot of trouble.

Comment: that's what I want to do eventually but, for now, given time constraint, I need a quick solution to do this.

Comment: denniss. I wonder if you did migrate entirely to PG, or whether you found a "quick solution".